# JPA @OneToMany And @ManyToOne bidirectional with Lazy loading

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities Member entity and Team entity.

I set multiple member are included to a team. (Member : team = N : 1)

This is my code about entities.

```
public class Member {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Team team;
```

}

```
public class Team {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "team")
private List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();
```

}

=================================================================

I'm trying to get members when retrieve a team with lazy loading.
Then I make a test.

```
@Test
void lazyLoadingTest1() {
    Team team = teamRepository.findById(1L).orElse(null);
    // I expected a savedTeam entity with a proxy members object and
    // to retrieve query when team.getMembers() method is invoked.
    System.out.println("team = " + team);
}
```

As I know, when teamRepository.findById(1L) method is invoked, hibernate retrieve with proxy members object and execute select query when some method of member is invoked in Lazy loading.

But my code is executing 2 query for team and member when teamRepository.findById(1L) is invoked.

It is a bit tricky to understand what is different Eager loading and Lazy loading in this case.

[image]

Comment: you call system.out wich will call team.toString() wich can call team.getMembers().toString()

Comment: yes @ShakirovRamil right toString includes all of properties such as Team

Comment: why don't you override toString method ? then you would find out the reason :)

Comment: Thank you Shakirov Ramil and Joonseo Lee! It works!
Honestly, I used the Data annotation of lombok for test and toString method is included in the  annoation.